# Is the "w" in flower parasitic?

Tags: etymology

The OED shows various forms for the word in related languages, including a few with the "w", but it is not clear to me how those are related, and how the "w" arose. I have seen examples of words that the OED has declared parasitic, such as "thunder", so it would seem that "flower" is not, but I do not know why.

Comment: Unlike the d in _thunder_, which is clearly apparent in pronunciation, the w in _flower_ is less obvious. _Hour_ and _flour_ have the same phonemic structure /aʊər/ (or /aʊr̩/ if you prefer), but no w in writing. So you can call it parasitic if you want to – if it is, it’s a parasitic letter, not a parasitic sound, which could be why the OED doesn’t mention it.

Comment: wow, good question. There is in fact a root \*bhlew- whence *bloom*, straight from Germanic, whereas *flower* is from \*bhleh3-, through Latin *flora*, Norman French, Middle English. French *fleur* shows umlautung as well; similar, *power* is cognate to *poeir*, also from Latin. I want to say, compare *fluff, puff*, but it's the dreaded "origin unknown".

Comment: oops, tell a lie, *bloom* is also down for \*bhleh3-. There is a \*bhlew- for *blue* (a relatively recent development for a color word), next to Latin *flavus* with similar semantics from \*bhel-; there are \*bhlew-(H)- "to overflow", which is odd next to \*pleh3-(w)- "to flow"; there's also \*bhew- "to grow, swell" for *beam*, Ger. *Baum* "tree" (cp. *Baumwolle* "cotton, wool", viz. *fluff*), also \*bhu- *to be(come)*, and much more, so I hope you can see how I got confused about a tentative root extension \*-w-.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - Some English dialects (the "posher" ones) maintain a difference in pronunciation between flower (/aʊə/) and flour (/aʊr̩/ or maybe /a:/).

Comment: @HarryAudus All the ‘posher’ English dialects (assuming by ‘English’ you mean ‘from England’, not ‘pertaining to the English language’) are non-rhotic and by definition have no distinction between /ə/ and /r̩/. A pronunciation something like [aː(œ)] is quite common in posh dialects, but in my experience it’s in free variation with [aʊə] in _all_ the examples I gave, including _flower_.